# Parallel request in Scrapy

Tags: python, parallel-processing, scrapy

I am stuck with this problem in Scrapy:
I am trying to fill my `item` in the function `parse_additional_info` and to do so I need to scrape a bunch of additional url in a second callback `parse_player`:

```
for path in path_player:
url = path.xpath('url_extractor').extract()[0]
          yield Request(url,meta = {'item' : item}, callback= self.parse_player, priority = 300)
```

When I do so my understanding is that the requests are executed asynchronously later on, filling `item` , however the `yield item` returns it immediately incompletely filled.
I know it is not possible to wait for all the `yield Request(url,meta = {'item' : item}, callback= self.parse_player, priority = 300)` to complete, but how would you solve this problem? i.e. making sure the `item` yield is done when all the infos from the request have completed.

```
from scrapy.spiders import Spider, CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import Request
from datetime import datetime
from footscript.items import MatchResultItem
import re, json, string, datetime, uuid

class PreliminarySpider(Spider):
  name = "script"
  start_urls = [
start_url1,
start_url2,
start_url3,
start_url4,
start_url5,
start_url6,
start_url7,
start_url8,
start_url9,
start_url10,
]
  allowed_domains = ['domain.com']

  def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    matches = sel.xpath('match_selector')
    for match in matches:
      try:
        item = MatchResultItem()
        item['url'] = match.xpath('match_url_extractor').extract()[0]
      except Exception:
        print "Unable to get: %s" % match.extract()
      yield Request(url=item['url'] ,meta = {'item' : item}, callback=self.parse_additional_info)

  def parse_additional_info(self, response):
    item = response.request.meta['item']
    sel = Selector(response)

    try:
      item['roun'] = sel.xpath('round_extractor').extract()[0]
      item['stadium'] = sel.xpath('stadium_extractor').extract()[0]
      item['attendance'] = sel.xpath('attendance_extractor').extract()[0]
    except Exception:
      print "Attributes not found at:" % item['url']

    item['player'] = []
    path_player = sel.xpath('path_extractor')
    for path in path_player:
      player = path.xpath('player_extractor').extract()[0]
      player_id = path.xpath('player_d_extractor').extract()[0]
      country = path.xpath('country_extractor').extract()[0]
      item['player'].append([player_id, player, country])
      url = path.xpath('url_extractor').extract()[0]
      yield Request(url,meta = {'item' : item}, callback= self.parse_player, priority = 300)
   # except Exception:
   #   print "Unable to get players"
    yield item

  def parse_player(self, response):
    item = response.request.meta['item']
    sel = Selector(response)
    play_id = re.sub("[^0-9]", "",response.url)
    name = sel.xpath('//div[@class="fdh-wrap contentheader"]/h1/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8').rstrip()
    index = [i for i, row in enumerate(item['player']) if play_id in row[0]]
    item['player'][index[0]][1]=name
    return item
```

**EDIT**
New code:

```
yield Request(url,meta = {'item' : item}, callback= self.parse_player, errback= self.err_player)
   # except Exception:
   #   print "Unable to get players"
    yield item

    def parse_player(self, response):
      item = response.request.meta['item']
      sel = Selector(response)
      play_id = re.sub("[^0-9]", "",response.url)
      name = sel.xpath('//div[@class="fdh-wrap contentheader"]/h1/text()').extract()[0].encode('utf-8').rstrip()
      index = [i for i, row in enumerate(item['player']) if play_id in row[0]]
      item['player'][index[0]][1]=name
      item['player'][index[0]].append("1")
      return item

    def err_player(self, response):
      print "****************"
      print "Player not found"
      print "****************"
      item = response.request.meta['item']
      play_id = re.sub("[^0-9]", "",response.url)
      index = [i for i, row in enumerate(item['player']) if play_id in row[0]]
      item['player'][index[0]].append("1")
      return item
```

Comment: why would you need that? the incomplete item yielded from `parse_additional_info` is later returned with the `player` field filled on `parse_player`

Comment: @eLRuLL I need it because in my pipeline I am filling a database and to do so I need to have all the players completed. An acceptable solution for me could be to process only completely filled items in the pipeline but i don't know how to do that. Ps: let me know if you'd like to see the pipeline.py code.

Comment: first, I hope you understand the `yield item` on `parse_additional_info` is not waiting for the requests of your previous `for` to end. Now maybe a better approach would be to create a pipeline that checks an ID on the item, and then keeps populating the same row on your database according to that ID. Another solution would be to do the same at the spider level (or even at the pipeline), with a class variable.

Comment: @eLRuLL based on your answer I am now reconstructing `item['player']` with an additional field set to `1 ` if the request was executed. The pipeline detects if the item has been fully updated based on this additional field.
I am also setting it to `1` in case of `errback` in the request. However some  url are scraped twice and since `dont_filter=False` certain fields are not updated. Is there a callback function that I can implement when Request are filtered? (I don't want to set `dont_filter=True` because it would create 100x more requests).

Comment: so new fields could be populated after some minutes doing the same request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

passing items across multiple callbacks is very delicate practice. It can work in very simple cases.
However you can meet all kind of issues:

- request fails ( you can fix it with `Request(..., errback=self.my_parse_err)` but it's quite tedious to create 2 callbacks for each request)
- second requests has duplicates urls ( you can fix it with `Request(...., dont_filter=True)`  and using adding `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED=True`  to `settings.py`)

The safe path, both from development perspective and production perspective, is to create 1 type of item for each type of page. Then combine 2 related items as a post processing.

Please also note that if you have duplicate urls you would probably end up with duplicate data in your items. This will also cause data normalisation issues in the database.

Comment: I am taking care of duplicates in my database requesting `UNIQUE` datasets - therefore it is not such a big issue for me. A big problem for me is when my request is failing and being able to catch that. Unfortunately it seems that some silent failures are possible which is troublesome for me.
Aside from this point: could you finish your sentence on the first point and maybe elaborate on `HTTPCACHE_ENABLED=True`as I am not familiar with this one.

Comment: I updated answer, let me know if there s still something to clarify

Comment: after some time I did indeed implement what you suggested, only one item though put with post-processing in the pipeline.

Comment: @vrleboss can you post the final sample of postprocessing pipeleine too